# SSDT: timeout in create database script

Tags: timeout, sql-server-data-tools

We have recently moved to SSDT for our database management and deployment tool. We are using SqlPackage.exe to deploy the package. We are occasionally getting timeout errors when deploying the package. After looking at the errors, I added /p:CommandTimeout=900 in the commandline parameters of the sqlpackage. But it is still failing on some occasions and when it fails, it fails within few seconds. So I'm guessing it is not hitting that p:CommandTimeout.

I couldn't find documentation on any other timeout.

Here is the detailed error message -

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg -2, Level 11, State
>   0, Line 0 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. Error
>   SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [PhoenixDB], FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)PhoenixDB_Data.mdf', SIZE = 8000 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %)
    LOG ON (NAME = [PhoenixDB_log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)PhoenixDB_Log.ldf', SIZE = 2000 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1802, Level 16,
>   State 4, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could
>   not be created. Check related errors. Error SQL72045: Script execution
>   error.  The executed script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [PhoenixDB], FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)PhoenixDB_Data.mdf', SIZE = 8000 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %)
    LOG ON (NAME = [PhoenixDB_log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)PhoenixDB_Log.ldf', SIZE = 2000 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Comment: what happens when you run scripts directly in SSMS by using same credentials?

Comment: It works fine from SSMS. It also works fine sometimes from SSDT.